# TextSwitcher in Recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

TextSwitchers switch your text each time your setText and you can insert animations within the textSwitcher so that it slides up and down when you setText like the example below. A use case for this would be like a like button in an app, where the user clicks like and the textSwitcher slides up to show the new like count.

[image: textswitcher]

I'm struggling with using a textSwitcher in a recyclerview and have created a small repo to demonstrate my problem: https://github.com/Winghin2517/TextSwitcherRV

My problem is that if I scroll, the textSwitcher animations activates itself and I can see the textSwitcher in each line flicker up and down again like those signboards in the airport.

I think this is due to views recycling itself and hence the textSwitcher resetting itself but was wondering if there is a way to stop this airport signboard effect when scrolling through the recyclerview?

I would imagine putting textSwitchers in recyclerview is a pretty common use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (mDataset.get(position).isClicked()) {
                ((TextViewHolder) holder).textSwitcher.setText("I was clicked!");
            } else {
                ((TextViewHolder) holder).textSwitcher.setText(mDataset.get(position).getCounter());
        }
```

I think this is because you set the text to textSwitcher without checking if the text is already set and  where the viewholder get reused it starts to animate to the new value (which in fact equals to the old one).

Try to set the text via `setCurrentText`, this will not trigger the animation.